# Need to dynamically generate UITableView items from JSON. What is the best approach?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode

Lets say I have an array of JSON objects like this:

```
{
  "views": [
    {
    "type": "UILabel",
    "data": "Here is a headline",
    "id": "label1"
    },
    {
    "type": "UIImage",
    "data": "http://doge2048.com/meta/doge-600.png",
    "id": "image1"
    },
    {
    "type": "UIButton",
    "data": "Click me",
    "id": "button1"
    }
  ]
}
```

This is how this item should look like for example.
[image: This is how this item should look like for example.]

- Each table cell will have different JSON, so I can't design them in Storyboard.
- Dynamic views can even be UIStackViews, so I can't just create a main UIStackView and add these in it. (Because it lags very bad.)
- Data source and structure is not a problem. My question is how to construct the UI and constraints.

Comment: Are you getting an array of NSDictionary as your JSON response?

Comment: It is irrelevant. I already handle the JSON quite well. The problem is creating the UI with it.

Comment: Just you need to serialize your json response and pass that data into tableview datasource method + design custom cell for show your data in tableview.

Comment: So the json will have all the views supposed to be inside the cell or is it fixed that it will have a label, an image and a button?

Comment: have you seen NSClassFromString?

Comment: My question is not as clear as I hoped i suppose. I am asking about how to create constraints and how to add views to master view of cell.

Comment: `I am asking about how to create constraints and how to add views to master view of cell.` Then you have an issue, because your question looks like one of those "hey I have this JSON and I need to make a tableView like this screenshot" showing absolutely no effort. If your question is not like this, if you have a specific question instead, please edit and refactor and expose your real issue, explain where you struggle, what you don't understand, etc. *Give information*. :)

Comment: What I understood is that you want help in creating a dynamic UI with constraints based on the json. But the json doesn't provide enough details to define a constraint. unless, you want the image to be an aspect fit wherein if its small, it will just conform to its own size something like that.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a custom type of UITableViewCell for each type of supported element

   - LabelCell
   - ImageCell
   - ButtonCell
2. Generate table view cells by passing json content of each element(the view model) to the corresponding cell type

jsonContent = {
    "type": "UILabel",
    "data": "Here is a headline",
    "id": "label1"
    }
LabelCell(viewModel:jsonContent)

You might need to used **Sell sizing table view cell** to let cell height adjust itself automatically.

Check this link:
https://www.raywenderlich.com/129059/self-sizing-table-view-cells

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Parse the JSON data into model classes immediately after receiving it.

Step 2: That data model becomes the data source of your table view. When it changes, you update the table view.

Step 3: As with every table view, you have your methods to fill table view cells from the data model, so that's what you do.

How to construct the UI and constraints: By writing code.